# Trazado en TextView

Tags: android, textview

Tengo un `TextView` y me gustaría realizar por codigo la manera de darle trazado,como se ve en la imagen de abajo. Si no fuera posible dos trazados,al menos uno.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No creo que sea posible utilizando `drawable` ya que solo se peude cambiar el border de un View, no el fontWeigth de un texto en si. Tendras que dibujar las letras utilizando un canvas o buscar un font pero no creo que podras cambiarle el color de los borders a las letras.

Comment: Yo creo que tu mejor opción es un font ..